# Difference between spacy_sklearn and tensorflow_embedding pipelines

Tags: machine-learning, rasa-nlu

I want to know if there is any basic difference between how spacy_sklearn and tensorflow_embedding pipelines operate under the hood.I mean tensorflow_embedding must also be using the same concepts of word embeddings,reducing the dimensionality of data using PCA etc. Is the only difference then that spacy_sklearn has some pre trained data to draw upon in the form of pre trained vectors and tensorflow pipeline does not?Is my understanding correct?Also how is tensorflow_embedding pipeline related to the tensorflow framework offered by google?

I tried looking up tensorflow framework on google, but could not get any specific answer.I also searched about it on RASA community page, but again found no help

Answer (score 0):

The spacy_sklearn pipeline uses pre-trained word vectors.This is useful if we don’t have very much training data.

The tensorflow embedding pipeline doesn’t use any pre-trained word vectors,it fits specifically for our dataset. The advantage of the tensorflow_embedding pipeline is that the word vectors will be customised for our domain.

For more information ,please refer the below link
https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/choosing_pipeline/